# UITableView resizing when moving the container UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an application where I'm moving my entire `UIView` up when using the keyboard, in order to not hide some important `UITextField`s.

My problem is that the `UITableView` that I have there does not behave the same way as all the other views. Instead of moving the entire `UITableView`, it moves only its top edge, and that resizes the `UITableView` which is not the desired effect.

My problem is better described here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVJVMiBULEQ

This is the code that I'm using for the animation:

```
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // if you want to slide up the view
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGRect rect = self.view.frame;

    if (movedUp) {
        // 1. move the view's origin up so that the text field that will be hidden come above the keyboard 
        // 2. increase the size of the view so that the area behind the keyboard is covered up.
        rect.origin.y -= 140;
        rect.size.height += 140;
    } else {
        // revert back to the normal state.
        rect.origin.y += 140;
        rect.size.height -= 140;
    }

    self.view.frame = rect;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Hm, I always do this by setting transform self.transfom = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,-140) and self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity (move down). Can you try this and see if you get the same result?

Comment: Thanks. This worked but it moves instantly, without any animation. Is there any way to add animation to this?

Comment: Solved by changing the autosizing option in Interface Builder. =) It was sticking on resize.

Comment: Cool, happy you solved it. Previous comment > put it inside an animation block like you did with the frame resizing.

Comment: Put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As solved in comments above, code above works when view is not autoresizing. The simpler approach would be to use CGAffineTransform transformations that calculate view frame instead of you.

```
-(void)setViewMovedUp:(BOOL)movedUp {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // if you want to slide up the view
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    if (movedUp) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -150);//move up for 150 px
    } else {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;//reset to initial frame
    }

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```